# Delete and Update of Foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm working on a school project. And I'm required to implement it using Java-EE and SQL Server. I want the design to withstand any kind of faulty user requests. My questions are how should I design the tables and the relationships such that deletions are safe.
In addition i want to know how to log these changes.

Comment: **how is it now?**

Comment: I think you made it *more* broad... I suggest doing some searching around to see what kind of solutions are out there, so the focus can be narrowed based on your business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to not actually delete rows, but to set an "IsDeleted" column to 1. That way, referring records remain unorphaned.

Updates are more interesting. Do you need to have the referring record still refer to the old record, or the new version?

Comment: on update; i want to refer the new one. The problem on delete i have though is that i don't want the referers to refer to a deleted row. That would be like using a row that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok. If it goes to the new one, just make sure you don't change the primary key in that table, so that any references to it don't get lost. So the "logical delete" technique should work.